# Application running on Iinux OS (custom board) does not reads the shared libraries from the exported LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: c++, c, linux, ld

I am trying to run an application (`a.out`), very small application contains only one print statement) on Linux OS custom board which is not having the shared libs in `/lib` or `/usr/lib`.

So I am exporting the shared libs path using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/media/opensourcelib/toolchainLib/ramfslib
```

I made sure, shared libraries are in this path `/media/opensourcelib/toolchainLib/ramfslib`

Still, after this, when I execute `a.out` I get the error

```
/bin/sh: ./../usr/lib/a.out: not found
```

If I copy my shared  libs to `/lib`, the application works fine.

But I need to make it work without copying the shared libs. Please help me, what could be the issue in exporting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Did you run `ldconfig` after exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: The message a.out not found sounds like it is referring to the executable, not the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following things:

1. Check that the path is correct. Maybe an uppercase or lowercase letter or any other misspelling mistake. Try `ls /media/opensourcelib/toolchainLib/ramfslib`, before any other thing, and check that the library is there.
2. Check that the necessary soft links exist into the path for the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. This is one of the things that do `ldconfig`. Maybe for your `libmylib.so.1.5.8` you will find the links `libmylib.so.1.5`, `libmylib.so.1` and `libmylib.so`.
3. Check the library dependencies with `ldd a.out`.
4. If you have `strace` installed into the system (if not, I recommend to compile it for your board and copy it to your board), try to launch it exporting previously `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and verify the paths are tried to read (and a many other things).

I hope it could be helpful.

Comment: IMO #4, using `strace ./a.out`, would be the simplest way of getting an explicit report of what is considered "missing".  The *last* `open()` that returns ENOENT should be the culprit.